Axios: Filtered out request cookies problem
I have a problem with cookies when I make a request.
When I make the first request it's all ok, the cookies are ok.
first auth request

The same happens for the second request
second auth request

now i successfully authenticated and i can call a web service and here's the problem:
ws call

the cookies are not sent and I am asked to re-authenticate.
I'm doing this inside an application made with Vue.
The problem happens in this case:
I have a class that does mock of a library
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export class WAFData {
  constructor() {
    this.defaultRequest = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
      },
      data: null,
      async: true,
      type: "",
      timeout: 25000,
      responseType: "text",
      cache: -1,
      proxy: "ajax",
      withCredentials: false,
      onComplete: () => {},
      onFailure: (error, result, headers) => {
        throw error;
      },
      onPassportError: () => {
        throw new Error("Passport error...");
      },
      onTimeout: (error) => {
        throw error;
      },
      onProgress: () => {},
      onUploadProgress: () => {},
    };
  }
  getHeaders(xhr) {
    const headers = {};
    const arr = xhr
      .getAllResponseHeaders()
      .trim()
      .split(/[\r\n]+/);
    arr.forEach((line) => {
      const parts = line.split(": ");
      const header = parts.shift();
      const value = parts.join(": ");
      if (header) headers[header] = value;
    });
    return headers;
  }
  handleRedirect(xhr, allOptions) {
    const { onFailure, onPassportError, onTimeout } = allOptions;
    const redirRes = this.request(xhr.response.x3ds_auth_url, {
      onFailure: () => {
        const response = JSON.parse(redirRes.xhr.response);
        console.error(response.error_description);
        onFailure(
          new Error(response.error_description),
          redirRes.xhr.response,
          this.getHeaders(redirRes.xhr)
        );
      },
      onPassportError,
      onTimeout,
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
      withCredentials: false,
      onComplete: (resp) => {
        /*  const redirUrlWithServiceTicket =
          JSON.parse(resp)?.x3ds_service_redirect_url;
        if (redirUrlWithServiceTicket)
          this.request(redirUrlWithServiceTicket, allOptions); */
      },
    });
  }
  async request(url, options) {
    const allOptions = {
      ...this.defaultRequest,
      ...options,
    };
    const {
      method,
      headers,
      data,
      timeout,
      responseType,
      withCredentials,
      onComplete,
      onFailure,
      onProgress,
      onUploadProgress,
      params,
    } = allOptions;

    const urlObj = new URL(url);
    if (!urlObj.searchParams.get("xrequestedwith")) {
      urlObj.searchParams.set("xrequestedwith", "xmlhttprequest");
      headers["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
    } 

    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: method,
        url: urlObj.toString(),
        headers: headers,
        data: data,
        timeout: timeout,
        responseType: responseType,
        withCredentials: false,
        onUploadProgress: onUploadProgress,
        params: params,
      });

      const sessionCookie = response.headers["set-cookie"];
      if (sessionCookie) {
        Cookies.set("session", sessionCookie);
      }
      onComplete?.(response.data, response.headers);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        onFailure?.(
          new Error(
            `URL "${url}" return ResponseCode with value "${error.response.status}"`
          ),
          error.response.data,
          error.response.headers
        );
      } else if (error.request) {
        onFailure?.(
          new Error(
            `The request was made but no response was received. ${error.message}`
          ),
          null,
          null
        );
      } else {
        onFailure?.(
          new Error(
            `Something happened in setting up the request and triggered an Error: ${error.message}`
          ),
          null,
          null
        );
      }
    }
  }

  authenticatedRequest(url, options) {
    return this.request(url, options);
  }
}

i'm using **authenticatedRequest ** to make requests ang i got the above error.
But when I do the whole process of authentication and calling the webservice without the authenticatedRequest method of WAFData class but using functions it's working, for example:
export async function getAuthParams() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      process.env.VUE_APP_SERVICE_ + "/login",
      {
        //withCredentials: true,
        params: {
          action: "get_auth_params",
        },
        headers: {
          "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
          
        },
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}

